# If Else in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
select something from myTable
where curentFlag = 'Y'
and
case when @Year2 is not NULL then  
 AYEAR >= @Year AND AYEAR <= @Year2
else
 AYEAR= isnull(@Year ,AYEAR)  
end
        ADATE = ISNULL(@Date, ADATE)
```

But this yields:

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ADATE'.

The user should be able to search by a year (equals to) or a year range. So I'm either passing in just `@YEAR` or both `@YEAR` and `@YEAR2`. So let's say my data set:

```
DECLARE @y TABLE(AYEAR INT);
INSERT @y VALUES(2008),(2010),(2010);
```

Now I have these variables:

```
DECLARE @YEAR INT, @YEAR2 INT;
```

- If I pass in `@YEAR = 2008` I should get 1 result.
- If I pass in `@YEAR = 2010` I should get 2 results.
- If I pass in `@YEAR = 2008` and `@YEAR2 = 2010` I should get all 3 results.

Comment: You need to post more of your code (the part before `WHERE`) so we can get some context. The syntax you posted is nowhere near correct, but it's difficult to tell you how to fix it without more info.

Comment: here is the [case on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Comment: Did you mean `@YEAR2=2010`? And what if `@YEAR` is null and so is `@YEAR2`? What if only `@YEAR2` has a value?

Comment: this wont' happen because of my .net checks on the form. it will either be only year, or both year and year2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single value. It cannot be used for control of flow logic.

If you are sure that `@Year` will always be populated and `@Year2` will only sometimes be populated, than this much simpler logic should work:

```
WHERE CURRENTFLAG = 'Y'
AND AYEAR BETWEEN @Year AND COALESCE(@Year2, @Year)
AND ADATE = COALESCE(@Date, ADATE);
```

You can try it with a very simple example:

```
DECLARE @y TABLE(AYEAR INT);
INSERT @y VALUES(2008),(2010),(2010);

DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2008, @YEAR2 INT = 2010;
--DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2008, @YEAR2 INT = NULL;
--DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2010, @YEAR2 INT = NULL;

SELECT AYEAR FROM @y 
  WHERE AYEAR BETWEEN @YEAR AND COALESCE(@YEAR2, @YEAR);
```

Comment: just tried it, does nto work, it gives me everything even if i only pass in Year and null for  Year2. i only want to display resutls for @year if that's the only one passed in, and a range if both are passed in.

Comment: @Tanya then please post some sample data and desired results so we don't have to guess what you're after based on incorrect syntax. Also, what if neither are passed in?

Comment: @Tanya uh, I took that from your question: `ADATE = ISNULL(@Date, ADATE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 where CURRENTFLAG = 'Y' 
    case when @Year2 is not NULL then  --after THEN should be statement or BEGIN block not AND
 and AYEAR >= @Year AND AYEAR <= @Year2
    else
     AND  AYEAR= isnull(@Year ,AYEAR)   -- here also
    end
        and    ADATE = ISNULL(@Date, ADATE)
```

Comment: No, `CASE` is not a control of flow statement in T-SQL, it is an *expression*. THere is no `BEGIN` after `THEN`. You are thinking of `IF` or perhaps how `CASE` works in other languages like VBScript.